# Char vector Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi I am trying to make a vector with char variable.

This is my code:

```
h='wudh2h2';
w='uwuuw';
v = [h w]
t = v(1);
```

THe result is `t='w'`

Why is `t` not `t='wudh2h2'` ?

Comment: This will work as intended if instead of a vector you use [cell arrays](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). Because MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in Matlab you don't use matrices as an element of another matrix. You simply copy the whole matrix and and paste it everywhere when you have a usage like that.

The code you are looking for is like:

```
t = v(1:length(h));
```

that will do the work. The code basically means **start from the 1'st item and keep going until you reach the length of h matrix. Then copy all the things you have found and assign that things to t matrix.**

Answer (score 2):

Strings are a relatively new development in MATLAB, actually. So if you have MATLAB version **2016b** or later, you can run this code instead, and get the result you're looking for (it is identical to your code, but the single quotes are replaced with double quotes).

```
h = "wudh2h2";
w = "uwuuw";
v = [h w];
t = v(1);
```

However, most people are probably still running older versions of matlab, so it's better to create a cell array of character strings instead. This ensures that each string is preserved within the cells, and can be accessed without knowing the their lengths beforehand.

```
v = cell(2, 1)    % This creates a 2x1 cell array 
v{1} = 'wudh2h2';
v{2} = 'uwuuw';
t = v{1};
```

I guess to answer your question about why you can't implement it your way. MATLAB doesnt (before R2016b) have Strings the way other languages do. When you do something like `h='wudh2h2';`, you're actually creating a character array which looks like `[w, u, d, h, 2, h, 2]`. So when you concatenate the arrays by doing `v = [h w]`, you're just creating a longer character array; the two original "strings" are no longer distinguishable. The line `v(1)` is simply calling the first element of your character array, which is the *character* `w`.

Comment: +1, I learned something from this. One of the reasons I dropped MATLAB was exactly this "MATLAB doesnt have [. . .] the way other languages do" and this is a huge waste of time when you are trying to solve a problem.